# How to setup chrome driver for selenium django applaication hosted on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, selenium-chromedriver

I hosted my django application on aws ec2 instance but i have a problem with chrome driver selenium for web scrapping  an error is showen

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.